# within in ScatterGatherFirstCompletedRouter

Tags: scala, akka

I am going through Akka [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/routing.html) and could not understand one argument. I tried searching over the Internet and [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface), but I could not reason out this.

[ScatterGatherFirstCompletedRouter](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.1.4/#akka.routing.ScatterGatherFirstCompletedRouter) is defined with one of the constructor argument as

```
within: FiniteDuration
```

The documentation only says

> You have to define the 'within: Duration' parameter (for example: within = 10 seconds).

But it does not explain what it means. What does `within` mean above? In fact at many a places in the Akka API, the arguments are not explained, leaving me bewildered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [source](https://github.com/akka/akka) when documentation isn't enough.

`within` is used to specify how long to wait for first answer.

According to [usage of `within`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/routing/Routing.scala#L1290) and [definition of `PromiseActorRef`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/pattern/AskSupport.scala#L334) after `within` you'll [get](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/pattern/PipeToSupport.scala#L18) `Status.Failure(AskTimeoutException("Timed out"))` as response.